# What permits and reservations do I need for the Adirondacks?

Tags: backpacking, camping, united-states

I'm considering to go on a multi-day backpacking hiking trip in the Adirondack Mountains, New York, USA, soon.  In Canada one must often purchase a permit and reservations, and one can only camp on specific campgrounds.  I was looking for information at the Adirondack Park Agency (APA), but their [FAQ](http://apa.ny.gov/Faqs/faqs.cfm) does not seem to contain any answer.

For a multi-day hike in the Adirondack Mountains, do I need permits and reservations?  Where can I camp?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

http://visitadirondacks.com/stay/campgrounds/backcountry-camping-rules-guidelines

You only need a permit if your group is 10+ or you are staying in one location for more than 3 days. You don't need reservations for areas which allow primitive camping, but there are some campgrounds which require it. The Adirondacks are composed of a lot of areas with varying regulations, so where you can camp depends on your route, but most of the places allow primitive camping.

Comment: Also noted in the link above, "The use of bear-resistant canisters is required for overnight users in the Eastern High Peaks Wilderness between April 1 and November 30."

Answer (score 3):

If you are unfamiliar with the Adirondacks (ADK), the term "High Peaks" is the most talked about area for backpacking in the Adirondacks. They are the 46 tallest peaks in New York.

Jesse Black's link was great, its provided by the ADK tourism council. The "state government's authoritative" site is a terrible mess for the information you are looking for, but [here it is](http://www.dec.ny.gov/outdoor/camping.html). It gives a little more information about camping at specific elevations.

Check [trail and weather conditions](https://www.adk.org/play/hiking-information/hiking-in-the-adirondacks/high-peaks-trail-conditions-weather/).

You might also find a lot of useful information from the [Adirondack Mountain Club](https://www.adk.org/).

Make sure you bring paper trail and road maps. You can't rely on your cell phone for much of anything in the Adirondacks. There are towers near towns, but for the most part, you will be on your own! If you have a GPS loaded with New York maps it is very helpful!

Comment: I have six metric 1:25,000 topos and the National Geographic overview map for the High Peaks :).  Thanks for the additional links.  I'm leaving tomorrow from Corey's Road.  Hopefully it won't be too crowded.